# Open URL in Android App?

Tags: android

I use the following to open a url from my app:

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

But when I test it in the simulator, it goes back to eclipse and states source not found.

Whats going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually do it like this:

> Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.example.com");
>
> Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
>
> startActivity(intent);

Also, does your simulator have the browser app installed on it?

Comment: I think so, ad mob test ads load the browser, is there any way to check for definite?

Comment: hm also is this is debug mode?  'source not found' usually means eclipse cannot find the source files when debugging (ex: anything you import to use).  I would try running in non-debug mode or not stepping into code not available for eclipse to access.